# How to change color of a search word in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

So in my HTML file, I have

> `<p class = "result">  {{searchResult}} </p>`

where {{searchResult}} is essentially my result.
So if I searched for the term "hot", 
{{searchResult}} would contain a string containing the word "hot" in a document.
For example:

"This is hot"

Everything shows up in the webpage perfectly fine but I want to change the color of the search term within the string.

I tried modifying the part where it should output the content in my JS file:

```
content: result.replace(searchTerm, <span class= "search">searchTerm</span>)
```

where the class "search" is just changing the color of the word.

But it shows up as the webpage as:
This is `<span class = "search">hot</span>`

How would I make it so that it changes the color only of the search term?

Comment: can you add the javascript which adds the `content` to the page?

Comment: replace() replaces strings, as text. You need to trigger it to parse the result of that replacement as html so the DOM gets updated. Or you can insert the elements in the DOM yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to change the `style` of the `html` content. This is done using `CSS`. You can do this in one of three ways:

1) Edit the color of the paragraph using in-line CSS: `<p class="result" style="color:red;"> {{searchResult}} </p>`

2) Create an external `.css` file and link your `html` file to it in the `<head>` of the document. Use similar `css` there:

```
.result {
  color:red;
}
```

3) Edit the `DOM` using `Javascript` to similarly change the color:

```
document.querySelector('.result').style.color='red';
```